# Cordiva CDVViewController crash gives 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

Tags: iphone, ios

I want create native ios app with "Cleaver" element WebView, but at compilation in simulator I get crash with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
```

It's My code ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 450);
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.  This is not a solution, but I got CDVViewController working using earlier version of PhoneGap (2.4.0) without problems.