# "CALayerInvalidGeometry" error on iPads with iOS6 (Phonegap)

Tags: ios, cordova

I've got a Phonegap application that works fine on iPads with iOS5 (e.g. original iPad), as well as various flavors of iPhone and iPod Touch; as well as Android tablets and phones. The only population that gets this error is iPads with iOS6. *For what it's worth, I've personally tested on two different iPad Minis but don't have a 10" iPad2 with which to test; and the client is reporting the same issue on a full size iPad 2 [retina]...*

Also worth noting: I'm using the [Phonegap:Build](http://build.phonegap.com) service.

The application crashes more or less instantly; before the splash screen even comes up. The console shows the following error after the crash:

> <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
> (0x33efd2a3 0x3bda897f 0x33efd1c5 0x35ab197b 0x35ab18a3 0x35ab1833 0x35d06aed 0x35d06815 0x35d06753 0x974d9 0x971eb 0x96d77 0x9763f 0x9d67d 0x9d8f1 0x9bd91 0x71fa5 0x35d24595 0x35d64d79 0x35d60aed 0x35da21e9 0x71d07 0x35d65ad9 0x35d65663 0x35d5d84b 0x35d05c39 0x35d056cd 0x35d0511b 0x37a105a3 0x37a101d3 0x33ed2173 0x33ed2117 0x33ed0f99 0x33e43ebd 0x33e43d49 0x35d5c485 0x35d59301 0x71ac7 0x71aa0)

I've [reported this issue to Adobe](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_crashes_on_ipad_running_ios_complains_about_invalid_geometry) but they've yet to acknowledge the issue. I've also googled pretty extensively and I can't find many cases of people getting this error with Phonegap. Just [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729040/cordiva-cdvviewcontroller-crash-gives-calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer), asked (poorly?) 5 days ago and with 0 answers...

Of course there are plenty of instances [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867968/calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-0-0-nan-nan-cr), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023321/ios-calayerinvalidgeometry), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864096/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-cal), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486441/calayerinvalidgeometrycalayerinvalidgeometry)] of people getting the **CALayerInvalidGeometry** exception when coding native Objective-C, but I'm not finding anything I can put to use in my Phonegap application.

Given that the application runs fine on OG iPad, iPhones, iPod Touches, and Android Phones & Tablets, I'm inclined to believe that the issue is a bug in Phonegap:Build. Is there something I can do to verify this hypothesis?

Does anyone have any advice for things I could try in order to fix or work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This known Cordova bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2846) occurs if the Default Image (splash screen) for a certain device is not available at startup. Work around by including (dummy) Default Images for all resolutions.

This bug has been resolved in 2.8.0. There is also [a patch for 2.7.0](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=blobdiff;f=CordovaLib/Classes/CDVSplashScreen.m;h=fdb79fa307e4f38ddaef8211ea4a6f2adabb0fc6;hp=45889a0e71f1677601886c6ce6ac8c399a24d661;hb=bbf78ac83fd920c59e5a393942933e7e2eabb6de;hpb=b3a2554666e5aeae494eaadbd39f88c97ce79b84).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my app running on iPads w/ iOS6 by downgrading to Cordova 2.5. This would seem to lend credence to the idea that there is a bug in Phonegap:Build's implementation of Cordova 2.7. I've [reported this detail in my bug report](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_crashes_on_ipad_running_ios_complains_about_invalid_geometry).